# How to send a script from one page to another in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to send some javascript from one file to another in my own server. For example on file 1 I have the following code:

```
<script>

   alert("Hey There!");

</script>
```

I want to send this code to file 2, so that the alert happens on file 2. Imagine File 2 had already loaded, I want to perform some processing on File 1 and based on the result of said processing I want to send something to File 2.

File 2 should not be sending any requests to File 1, File 1 should be doing all the sending, and File 2 should receive the message without page refresh.

Is this possible?

### EDIT

Imagine I have 3 files (2 html and 1 js). File A has already loaded, there's nothing in there. The js file is call "sayHello.js", it has the following content:

```
alert('Indeed 10 is less than 100');
```

File B has the following content:

```
if (10 < 100) {

   // attach the js file "sayHello.js" to File A

}
```

How would I be able to attach the js file to File A from File B (using the jQuery.getScript() method) and have the script execute on File A?

Comment: So you want client-to-client communication?

Comment: So you have two HTML files ? Is the user navigating from the first to the second HTML file ? Or are you talking about the user having the two files loaded in two separate browser tabs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally - you have to separate in your thinking what runs where - what code runs on the server and what code runs on the browser.
In the more complicated cases - the JavaScript that runs on the client would be generated by a server page that generates relevant JavaScript in according to the request context - in this case you have to remember well the order of operations.

Taking the simple premise that you refer communication on the client between code - you should keep in mind that the files do not process anything - they load JavaScript code to the root scope of the browser, and the browser executes it. 
In that manner you have to separate between commands and definitions, while every file that loads can access all the "members" that were introduced to the root scope by formerly loaded scripts (the right name is for these members is symbols, i.e - all functions and variables).

Discussing your two files - 
File 2 looks like a "main" to me, and file 1 looks like a "utility/library" to me.

So, instead of executing code on the root scope on file 1 - you have to define functions - where these functions would be accessible to file 2.

Your HTML:

```
<script src="File1.js"></script>
<!-- if you need to exectute the code in File1 - you can call it like this -->
<script>
   actionInFile1()
</script>
<script src="File2.js"></script>
```

File 1:

```
function actionInFile1(){
    alert("Hey There!")
}
```

File 2:

```
actionInFile1();
```

Having that in mind - I think that what you're describing is a dynamic load of scripts to the client.

Adding a second script on the fly to the current page, using jQuery is done using 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Now - for a more complex example - 
Your HTML

```
<script src="jQuery.....js"></script>
<script src="File1.js"></script>
<button value="   go   "  onclick="toTrick()">
```

File1.js

```
function doStuff(){
     alert("Hey there!");
}
```

File2.js

```
function toTrick(){
    $.getScript('ajax/test.js'
               , function() {
                     doStuff();             
                 }
               );
}
```

**EDIT:**

What you need to read about is variables scope in JavaScript.

File A has the following content:

```
function notify(){
    alert('Indeed 10 is less than 100');
}
notify();
```

File B has the following content:

```
if (10 < 100) {
     //notify is defined in file A, however it will be accessible here
     // as long as file A is loaded before file B.
     notify();
}
```

HTML has the following content:

```
 <script src="FileA.js"></script><!-- defines "notify" and executes it immediately -->
 <script src="FileB.js"></script><!-- reuses notify() -->
```

Comment: thank you very much post the response, I'm quite new to js so I'm having a tough time understanding your answer. Can you please take a look at my edit and see if that is what you're describing. If so, then can you please give an example based on that exact scenerio - I will be able to grasp that better.

Comment: Generally - the first simple example - is just what you describe in your edit.
Instead of executing alert("Indeed...") in file 1 - put it inside a function, and call that function immediately: that execute the code in the function as well as contain it within a reusable function. However, doing so - you can call this function again from File B :)